# What is the best way to fetch data realtime in a Mern Application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, mongodb-query, mern

This is how am doing it with set setInterval but the challenge is am using a screen loader every time the state is loading and this disrupts the activity on the screen. It also seems like an expensive process!

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOrders());
    // Fetching orders every after 1 Minute
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch(getOrders());
    }, 60000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [dispatch]);
    
    return loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <Container fluid>
         ...
        </Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want real time updates you should use a push method from the server to the client. A common way to do this is to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) to listen on the client and push updates from the server when things change.

Comment: Thank you Antoine. I've gone through the docs. Wondering if it's possible to have both the node API server and WebSocket server running (listening) at the same time or I have to switch completely to WebSocket's server!

Comment: E.g with Websocket, I’ll have to have;
const server = require("http").createServer();
server.listen(3000);

Yet I already have; ```
const app = express();
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () =>
      winston.info(
        `Server Running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on Port: ${PORT}`
      )
    )
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(`${err}`));

Is that the right implementation to have app.listen & server.listen in the same index.js file ```